# How can I port forward in openshift without using oc client . Is there a way we can usejava client to portforward in a pod just like“oc port forward”

Tags: openshift, portforwarding, openshift-client-tools

I need to access a postgres database from my java code which resides in openshift cluster. I need a way to do so. without initiating port forwarding manually through oc port forward command.

I have tried using openshift java client class openshift connection factory to get the connection by passing server url and username password through which I log in to the console but it dint help.

Comment: An external Load Balancer service is most likely how you want to expose your database: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/

Answer (score 0):

(This is mostly just a more detailed version of Will Gordon's comment, so credit to him.)

It sounds like you are trying to expose a service (specifically Postgres) outside of your cluster. This is very common.

However the best method to do so does depend a bit on your physical infrastructure because we are by definition trying to integrate with your networking. Look at the docs for [Getting Traffic into your Cluster](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/expose_service/index.html). Routes are probably *not* what you want, because Postgres is a TCP protocol. But one of the other options in that chapter ([Load Balancer](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_load_balancer.html), [External IP](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_service.html), or [NodePort](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_nodeport.html)) is probably your best option depending on your networking infrastructure and needs.